# MacBook Pro 16" temperature issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, system-settings, temperature

I bought **MacBook Pro 16" 2019 model** 8 months back (Intel i7 version), and I can see that my MBP gets so much heat when I am using with external display and power adapter connected.

I live in western part of India and the current weather in my location is 42 celsius. When I use MBP in this temperature, the machine becomes so much slow and even it takes 7 seconds to open the *Finder* window.

When I ran the below command to see the temperature, I find an information as below. See the image below:

```
~ sudo powermetrics
```

[image]

**Is this normal?** If it is not, what should I do to prevent the heat and to use MBP normally in this situation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If the output is text please cut and paste that rather than a image